# How to do multithreading in node js child process

Tags: node.js, multithreading, child-process

I have a bash script that called for multiple times with unique id and I have used [socket io](https://socket.io/docs/) to send messages on stdout function

The shell script contains two actions:

> 1. Action1
> 2. Action2

Action2 is a background process so I don't want to wait for the script completion so when the Action1 got completed then I print echo message (msg) which I will capture in the stdout function and then I sent the socket io message inside the stdout function

server.js

```
child_process = exec('bash some-file.sh arg1 arg2')

child_process.stdout.on('data', function) {
  if ((data).indexOf(msg) > 1) {
    io.sockets.emit('Completed for id: ' + id)
  }
});
```

The problem with the above code is when I call the above action multiple times it doesn't work for second iteration (i.e id 1 still there) since the background action (Action2) is still running in the background for id 1.

How to do multithreading on child_process?

Comment: Would need to see both of the calls to really diagnose, and probably a more real example of your code. This could be because of all sorts of things. No way to tell without seeing the code!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `child_process.fork` and send the message from your subprocess (Actions2)

main.js

```
const child_proc = require('child_process');
const sub = child_proc.fork(`${__dirname}/sub.js`);
sub.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
});
sub.send({ from: 'server' });
```

sub.js

```
process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});
process.send({ from: 'client' });
```

Here are the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) and [a good article explained it](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a)